# AngularJS - Need To Change States Automatically On Timer Delay

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am quite new to AngularJS and have my web application using the `$stateProvider` to change to various states when required.

However, I am trying to find a way where I can loop through a number of different states on a timer.  So for example, when the application first loads, show Page1, then after 30 seconds show Page2, another 30 seconds show Page 3 and then return back to Page1 and so on...

Does anyone know if this is possible with Angular and `ui.router`?
If so, could you please point me in the right direction with an example or something.

Comment: $timeout(function() {$state.go(NEXT);}, 30000); in each controller

Comment: I'd suggest $interval as I assume there are conditions which will break the loop? If not and you are looking for just plain looping then go with $timeout.

Comment: I've tried both `$timeout` and `$interval` and I can't seem to get it to work.  My last example was $interval(function() {$state.go('alerts');}, 5000);  Doesn't give me any errors, just doesn't seem to change the state.  Am I missing something?

Comment: Here's a working [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/FebZ9zuBOd4xv7JUiZj7?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks @o4ohel  I can see it working exactly how I need in your plnkr, but can't seem to get mine to work.  I will keep playing around with it.

Comment: If you post your code, maybe a few set of eyes can catch something ...

Comment: All fixed!  I was calling the `$timeout` at the bottom of my controller and it didn't seem to fire.  I have moved this to the top of the controller code and everything now works great.  Thanks for the speedy resolution.  How can I make this as complete now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not entirely clear what objective is but you could use `$interval()` in a `run()` block if this is intended to start immediately ... or even if it's not intended to start right away

generally try to avoid putting things in rootScope but for a global method like is needed I don't think it's too bad and avoids needing to add repetitive code or inject anything in controllers

```
angular
    .module('myApp',[])
    .run(function($rootScope, $interval, $state) {
        var routeIdx = 0,
            routes = ['state1', 'state2','state3'];
        var routeTimer;

        $rootScope.routeLoop = {
            stopTimer: function() {
                $interval.cancel(routeTimer);
            },

            startTimer : function() {                  
                routeTimer = $interval(nextRoute, 1000);
            }
        }

        function nextRoute() {
            routeIdx++;
            if (routeIdx === routes.length) {
                routeIdx= 0;                   
            }
             $state.go(routes[routeIdx]);
        }
        // start it up
        $rootScope.routeLoop.startTimer()
    });
```

Now you have access to start and stop anywhere in your markup without having to add a bunch of code to each controller/directive

```
<button ng-click="routeLoop.stopTimer()">Stop</button>
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/vMKrq4891fkBWYo7qBZ3?p=preview)**</kbd>

Comment: Yes. That's a better (not having to add code in each ctrl) and more complete (allow start/stop) solution then the one in my comment. It should be the accepted answer.

Comment: How do I get this procedure to automatically start?  Testing this code snippet doesn't seem to load any page for me.

Comment: Sorry, didn't see the edits made to your example.  All working now.  Thankyou

Comment: Yeah sorry about that I wrote it before testing it and found minor flaws that were fixed

Comment: Thanks for your help.